# jQuery JSON parser: "Unexpected identifier" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have made a small (test) script that parses a JSON file (I use https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com in the example below) and makes table rows out of the resulting object.

I am trying to *append* these rows to a table.

See the jsFiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/o5vvcoc6/4/)**.

I get an `Unexpected identifier` error that I find inexplicable. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: See my **updated** fiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/o5vvcoc6/11/)**. Thanks to all that helped.

Comment: Please post your code here rather than only linking to an off site paste site.  Also please provide an example of the response being returned from the ajax request.

Comment: But from your fiddle you are trying to append to the table outside of the ajax request success method.  Not only is that an async error, but a scoping error as the variable is locally scoped to the success method.

Comment: Check out the answer i have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were appended the data wrong way. Replace your this portion of code by this.

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var tableRow = '';
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/users',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var tableRow = '<tr><td>' + data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data[i].email + '</td><td>' + data[i].email + '</td></tr>';
      $("#dataTable").find('tbody').append(tableRow);
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    var tableRow = '<tr><td>There is no data to display</td></tr>';
    console.log(tableRow);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @RazvanZamfir yes it looks fine now

Answer (score 0):

just move the part where you set your the html of the table inside the success and error handlers. ajax is async, you are calling the line`$("#dataTable tbody").html(tableRow);` before you get the actual response, so tableRow is still empty;

```
    var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var tableRow = '';
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/users',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(data) {
  var results = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      results += '<tr><td>' + data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data[i].email + '</td><td>' + data[i].email + '</td></tr>';
    }
          $("#dataTable tbody").html(results);

  },
  error: function() {
    var tableRow = '<tr><td>There is no data to display</td></tr>';
    console.log(tableRow);
    $("#dataTable tbody").html(tableRow);

  }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5vvcoc6/6/)

Comment: oops, let me update